# How to display or render multiple forms in django

Tags: python, django

[image]

I'm currently working on a personal project where in a page (purchases page), there will be the main form (includes product name, product category and product specifications fields).

now, there is a link "Add New Product Category" that activates the modal. This modal includes a separate form.

What you are seeing is the final output or what I want the page to be, i only did that in html, no django coding involve.

My (stupid) question is, how am i going to display BOTH forms? I don't understand how {{form}} works.

I successfully rendered the productCategoryForm in the modal by using the code `{{form}}` but when I do the same in the second form productDetailsForm it's not rendering or displaying. It's blank. I'm not sure how is this going to work.

Below is my Views.py and Forms.py codes.

**Views.py**

def addNewProduct(response):

```
c_form = productCategoryForm(response.POST)
p_form = productDetailsForm(response.POST)

if response.method == "POST":

    if c_form.is_valid():
        a = c_form.cleaned_data["productCategField"]
        b = productCategoryModel(productcategoryCol=a)
        b.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/acctg/purchases/")

    if p_form.is_valid():
        c = p_form.cleaned_data["productNameField"]
        d = productModel(productnameCol=c)
        d.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/acctg/purchases/")


context =  {
    "p_form": p_form,
    "c_form": c_form
}        

return render(response, 'purchases.html', context)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class productCategoryForm(forms.Form):
    productCategField = forms.CharField(label="Product Category", max_length=100, widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control col-sm-8 col-form-label'}))

class productDetailsForm(forms.Form):   
    productNameField = forms.CharField(label="Product Name", max_length=100, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter Product Name', 'class':'form-control col-sm-8 col-form-label'}))
```

**Models.py**

```
# Create your models here.
class productCategoryModel(models.Model):
    productcategoryCol = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.productcategoryCol

class productModel(models.Model):
    productnameCol = models.TextField()
    productspecsCol = models.TextField()
    #productcategCol = models.ForeignKey(productcategoryCol, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.productnameCol
```

Appreciate your help on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass both forms in your template through context.

```
def addNewProduct(request):
    p_form = productDetailsForm()
    c_form = productCategoryForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        p_form=productDetailsForm(request.POST)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()
            return redirect("/")
    context =  {
           "p_form": p_form,
           "c_form": c_form
             }
    return render(response, 'purchases.html', context)
```

Now in the template you can render both forms with `{{p_form}}` and
`{{c_form}}`. And provide different actions and different views for both forms.

**EDIT:**

If you want to handle both forms with a single view then you can use the name attribute in your submit button inside your template.

template:

```
  <form method='POST'>
    {{p_form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit" name="btn1">Add Product</button>
    </form>
    

    <form method='POST'>
    {{c_form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit" name="btn2">Add Category</button>
    </form>
```

Now in the views.

```
def addNewProduct(request):
    p_form = productDetailsForm()
    c_form = productCategoryForm()
    if request.method=='POST' and 'btn1' in request.POST:
        p_form=productDetailsForm(request.POST)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()
            return redirect("/")
    if request.method=='POST' and 'btn2' in request.POST:
        c_form=productCategoryForm(request.POST)
        if c_form.is_valid():
            c_form.save()
            return redirect("/")
    context =  {
       "p_form": p_form,
       "c_form": c_form
         }
    return render(response, 'purchases.html', context)
```

Comment: Hello! thanks for your answer. it perfectly solves my problem BUT I noticed in your code that only p_form will be saved. How about the c_form? I tried adding another IF c_form.is_valid() code block but it seems that it's not saving. i have updated my code above.

Comment: you can write another view with different action/url for saving `c_form` same as `p_form` @BenDaggers

Comment: understood! sorry @Arjun, i'm still a newbie trying to learn django thru youtube, dj documentations, stackoverflow and tutorials. This might be a stupid question to you :) but what will be the url of that? my goal is to have 2 forms ('add product category' and 'add new product') in one page.

Comment: they have different submit button. see my models.py and forms.py code.

Comment: Here above in my answer I have given example to save  `p_form` also with the option to render another `c_form`. Now for saving c_form you need to write another view same as above with different url and provide this url inside your `c_form` action. Or if you want it in a single view I'll update the answer.

Comment: yes please… thank u, i prefer the single view.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid spaghetti code I usually separate the views:

```
# views.py
def purchases(response):
    form = productCategoryForm()
    detailsForm = productDetailsForm()
    
    return render(response, 'purchases.html', {"form": form, "detailsForm": detailsForm})

@require_POST
def add_category(request):
    form = productCategoryForm(response.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        a = form.cleaned_data["productCateg"]
        b = productCategory(productCat=a)
        b.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect("/acctg/purchases/")

@require_POST
def add_product_details(request):
    form = productDetailsForm(response.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        #  your logic here
        b.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect("/acctg/purchases/")


# urls.py
path('purchases/', purchases, name='purchases'),
path('add_category/', add_category, name='add_category'),
path('add_product_details/', add_product_details, name='add_product_details'),


# purchases.html
            <form action="{% url 'add_category' %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form}}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>


            <form action="{% url 'add_product_details' %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{detailsForm}}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
```